# React APP ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs, browser-sync, gulp-watch

Integrating GULP with my React Project. On firing up the project, the following is the error that I face: https://prnt.sc/trw1if
Do check the screenshot above. This is a particular issue that I face.
Do let me know what am I doing wrong here. I've tried different presets for it as well. I am also attaching my GULP file here:

> ```
> var gulp = require('gulp');
> var babel = require('gulp-babel');
> var sass = require('gulp-sass');
> const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
> var concat = require('gulp-concat');
> var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
> var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
>
> const rollup = require('gulp-better-rollup');
> // const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');
> const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
> const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
>
> gulp.task('jsCompile', function () {
>   return gulp.src(['src/*.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'src/**/**/*.js'])
>       .pipe(babel({
>               presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
>           })
>           .on('error', function (err) {
>               console.log('[Compilation Error]');
>               console.log(err.fileName + (err.loc ? `( ${err.loc.line}, ${err.loc.column} ): ` : ': '));
>               console.log('error Babel: ' + err.message + '\n');
>               console.log(err.codeFrame);
>
>               this.emit('end');
>           }))
>       // .pipe(rollup({ plugins: [babel(), resolve(), commonjs()] }, 'umd'))
>       .pipe(uglify())
>       .pipe(concat('main.js'))
>       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
>       .pipe(browserSync.stream())
> });
>
> gulp.task('htmlCompile', function () {
>   return gulp.src(['public/*.html'])
>       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
> });
>
> gulp.task('sassCompile', function () {
>   return gulp.src(['src/*.scss', 'src/*.css'])
>       .pipe(concat('main.css'))
>       .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
>       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
> });
>
>
> gulp.task('imageCompile', function () {
>   return gulp.src(['src/assets/images/*.jpg', 'src/assets/images/*.png'])
>       .pipe(imagemin())
>       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'))
> });
>
> gulp.task('broswerReload', function () {
>   browserSync.init(["dist/css/*.css", "dist/js/*.js"], {
>       server: {
>           baseDir: "./dist"
>       }
>   })
> });
>
> gulp.task('serve', gulp.parallel('jsCompile', 'htmlCompile', 'imageCompile', 'broswerReload'), function () {
>
>   // gulp.watch(['src/*.scss', 'src/*.css'], ['sassCompile']);
>   gulp.watch('src/*.js', ['jsCompile']);
>   gulp.watch(['src/assets/images/*.jpg', 'src/assets/images/*.png'], ['imageCompile']);
>   gulp.watch('public/*.html', ['htmlCompile'])
>   // gulp.watch('public/*.html', ['htmlCompile']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
> });
>
> gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'));
> ```

Comment: How are you trying to run this program?

Comment: Using CMD with command *gulp*